# Via in Kicad connecting multiple layer?

Tags: layout, kicad, via

I am designing a four layer board in `Kicad`. The layer stack up is as follows:

1. SIGNAL
2. GROUND
3. POWER (3.3V)
4. SIGNAL

Now, i want to connect decoupling capacitor to SMD IC's. The decoupling capacitor is placed at the opposite side of the board. So, i am looking to get a `via` which connects `TOP` layer (where IC is soldered), `POWER` Layer and `BOTTOM` Layer. If it is not possible or it is not a good technique, then how can i connect decoupling caps and IC's Vcc when they are at opposite side of the board.

Should i have copper pour on TOP and BOTTOM layer of the board and should i connect them with GND or Power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place a via connecting the capacitor to the IC's power or ground pin, KiCAD (or any CAD program) should automagically connect the via to the power or ground layer as required.  Even a short track and via from the cap's power or ground pin should be automagically connected to the appropriate plane.

Generally, any via on the same net as an inner layer will be connected to that layer.  There should be no special effort required to make that connection.

Comment: Are you sure about kicad? I don't fabricate a faulty board.
What is your opinion on TOP and BOTTOM Copper pour?